# ejb in session context is allways null

Tags: jax-rs, ejb-3.1, java-ee-7, security-context

i have created sigleton session bean which keeps one connection to my mongo database. It works well in jax-rs class when using @EJB annotation - after controller is contructed and bean is injected it calls init method anotated with @PostConstruct.

Then i created similar class, which is implementing SecurityContext. I used same pattern as in controller, but it is not working properly. init() method is never called and EJB instance is always null.

So is there a way to inject EJB to my SecurityContext implemetation ? it works well unless i try to inject and use MongoConnection

my singleton session bean I use to connect mongo database:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MongoConnection {

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // initialize properties
}
```

I use it in JAX-RS controller. it works here, also in classes inherited from EntityController.

```
Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class EntityController extends Application {

@Context
private UriInfo context;

**@EJB
protected MongoConnection connection;**

public EntityController() {

@PostConstruct
void init() {
    ...
    connection.getMongo();
    connection.getDatabaseName();
    ...
}
}
```

I implemented my own security context, which is looking for loged user roles in mongo database.

```
public class MongoSecurityContext implements SecurityContext {

**@EJB
private MongoConnection connection;**


public MongoSecurityContext() {
}

@PostConstruct
void init() {
   ...
    connection.getMongo();
    connection.getDatabaseName();
    ...
}

public MongoSecurityContext(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    token = requestContext.getHeaderString("token");
}

@Override
public boolean isUserInRole(String roleName) {
    //**connection is allways null**, so it returns false;
    if (connection == null)
        return false;
}
}
```

EDIT:

I forget, i also have this warning in glassfish 4 console:

```
 A provider extremeteacher.mongo.connection.MongoConnectionEjb registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider extremeteacher.mongo.connection.MongoConnectionEjb will be ignored
```

EDIT2:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        requestContext.setSecurityContext(new MongoSecurityContext(requestContext)) ;

    }    
}
```

Comment: What kind of object is MongoSecurityContext? How is it created? Only EE objects created by the container (not via `new`) are eligible for injection.

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment. 

i put more code to question. I have an ContainerRequestFilter which sets my security context as context for all requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injection does not work for objects created with `new` because the container is never given control to perform the injection.  I recommend moving the `@EJB` to the filter and passing it to the MongoSecurityContext constructor.

Comment: thanks again. I believe you have good point. But now it's the same problem in that filter. i've added @EJB MongoConnection into filter a it's allways null. 

don't you know what could mean this warning in glassfish console ?

`A provider extremeteacher.mongo.connection.MongoConnection registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider extremeteacher.mongo.connection.MongoConnection will be ignored.`

Comment: Sorry, I misread and thought it was a servlet filter.  That sounds somewhat like a CDI error, but I don't know for sure, and I don't know what the problem might be.

Comment: well, i think you've answered my question well, now i have different problem. so i accepted your answer